# listItem field doesn't appear when searching item

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with SharePoint terms using the Microsoft Graph API.

I am doing the next HTTP Call:

```
GET sites/{Site-id}/drive/items/root/search(q='{term-id}')
```

This returns me a list of all the files that have the term that I specified. Here is an example:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-07-24T10:34:36Z",
            "id": "",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-29T09:43:00Z",
            "name": "file.docx",
            "webUrl": "",
            "size": 458332,
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "",
                    "displayName": ""
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "",
                    "displayName": "SharePoint App"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "driveType": "documentLibrary",
                "driveId": "",
                "id": "",
                "siteId": ""
            },
            "file": {
                "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                "hashes": {}
            },
            "fileSystemInfo": {
                "createdDateTime": "2023-07-24T10:34:36Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-29T09:43:00Z"
            },
            "searchResult": {},
            "shared": {
                "scope": "users"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the field "**listItem**" doesn't appear nowhere, I've read the official documentation of Microsoft Graph API, and in theory it should have that field. For example, in this similar call, **listItem** exists:

```
GET sites/{Site-id}/drive/items/root/children
```

In this call, at the beggining the field also didn't appear, but it was because in my headers I had this:

```
Prefer: apiversion=2.1
```

I've simply changed it to "2.0" and the field appeared again, but in the case of the first call that I've mentioned, despite also changing it to 2.0 it still doesn't appear.

I hope I've explained it right.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would add `$expand` query parameter and specify that `listItem` should be retrieved.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/root/search(q='{term-id}')?$expand=listItem
```

But for some unknown reason it returns the `notSupported` error.

Similar issue has been already [reported](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/896) many years ago. The result is that retrieving a `listItem` when searching items is not supported.

Comment: Yes, I was going crazy, I didn't understand why is not supported when on the official documentation they say that it should work. Maybe I will try to contact Microsoft to see if they can do something. Thank you.